# Can't link header files to node-gyp addon

Tags: node-gyp

I am trying to create a C/C++ addon for my Node application. I have created an addon.cpp file looking like this:

```
#include <node.h>
#include "src/prova.h"

namespace hellons {
    using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;;
    using v8::Isolate;
    using v8::Local;
    using v8::Object;
    using v8::Value;
    using v8::String;

    void method1 (const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>&args) {
        Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
        int result = hello();
        args.GetReturnValue().Set(result);
    }

    void Initialize (Local<Object> exports) {
        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "method1", method1);
    }

    NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Initialize);
}
```

It includes the prova.h file, located in the src folder, which has this content.

```
int hello(void);
```

The hello function is implemented in the prova.cpp file, which is located in the same directry (src):

```
int hello () {
    return 4;
}
```

In the binding.gyp file I have specified that all the 3 files should be included

```
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name": "addon",
            "sources": ["addon.cpp", "src/prova.h", "src/prova.cpp"],
            "include_dirs": [".", "src"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I built the project using the following command:

```
node-gyp configure build
```

What I eventually got is the following error

```
kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll) : fatal error LNK1103: debugging information corrupt; recompile module [C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\yyy\build\addon.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\yyy\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:203:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\xxx\\yyy\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\yyy
gyp ERR! node -v v16.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do to solve this problem has been deleting the build folder ad rebuilding.
Moreover I found out that my binding.gyp file could be simplified (apparently some things were not necessary). So now it's like this:

```
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name": "addon",
            "sources": ["addon.cpp", "src/prova.cpp"]
        }
    ]
}
```